# How to make jquery light for html grid?

Tags: jquery, html, delegates

We create a html grid dynamically. This has more than 5000 rows and 10 columns (this can grow). We currently add a "title" attribute to each  to show the tooltip on hover. Since we are adding attribute to all 5000x10 cells, it takes some time to add all those attributes and make the jQuery little heavy. I want to know is there any better and more efficient way of showing the tooltip on hover and reduce/lighten the jQuery? I am not sure if we can use delegates() or some other option?

```
function RenderGrid(colDefs,data){    
    .
    .
    var data='';
    for (var col in columnDefs) {
      data = d[colDefs[col].columnId] || '';
      rw[++i] = '<td title="' + data + '">';
      rw[++i] = data;
      rw[++i] = '</td>';
    }
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: Write your HTML and do not store it as an array. You'll safe memory in the output for sure. Instead of doing `rw[]` just do `$('element').append(data);`

Comment: @So I, sorry about that but you are right, I should go back and review my previous questions. But not sure how can I filter all my questions that I didn't accept yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.element-class').on('hover', function () {

//   create the tooltip element here;

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of duplicating the td text in the title attribute or storing it in data, just use the td text to set the title attribute when you hover.

```
$('td').on('hover', function () {
    $(this).attr("title", $(this).text());
});​
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hJzLa/).